# Sharepoint Online and Powershell SPDocumentLibrary

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, versioning

I was wondering if it is possible to update a Sharepoint List  versioning using powershell.

I have attempted to load the SPDocumentLibrary class into powershell by using

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
```

and attempted to load CSOM by using

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

I can cast my list object  to an SPDocumentLibrary  but I am then unable to update that list object

```
$docLib = ($a3 -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary])
$ctx.Load($docLib)
Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:1 + $ctx.Load($docLib)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I can not even use the Get-Member method to see what  methods or parameters I could use for this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with SharePoint remotely, you have to use CSOM and the CSOM model, you can't use any Microsoft.SharePoint.* objects.  Everything is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.*.

Start here to get acquainted with CSOM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

Comment: Kinda figured as much, I just have over 200 list where I need to update the versioning  to only hold 4 major version...